# ios "has active assertions beyond permitted time:" crash with async task

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

I sometimes get the crash "myApp has active assertions beyond permitted time:" in my today widget. After some googling, I guess it is caused because I handle background task inappropriately.

I use two type of background task. dispatch_async and NSURLConnection. I'm a newbie and I can't figure out which one is the problem. (There are already many questions and answers, but I can't find the one that fits in my situation)

Below is a shortened version of my code.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadData()
    }
    func loadData(){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)    ) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.actInd.startAnimating()
            }
            var pageSource=self.dpm.readData("https://url.com")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.refreshUI()
                self.actInd.stopAnimating()
            }
        }
    }
    func refreshUI(){
        //refresh UI
    }

    func readData(url:String)->NSData?{//This method is in a separate class. dpm
        var myUrl=NSURL(string: url)
        var request:NSMutableURLRequest=NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
        request.timeoutInterval=30
        let myHTMLData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

        return myHTMLData
    }
```

To sum up what I've intended:

1. On viewDidLoad, call loadData()
2. in loadData(), I used dispatch_async because I guess I should use different thread than main thread when loading data
3. In the async thread, I call readData(), thus call NSURLConnection. (I call sendSynchronousRequest, since I believe syncronousRequest is OK because it is already called in dispatch_async)
4. To refresh my UI after the loading is done, I call refreshUI()

It works, but sometimes it crashes...Is my idea wrong??

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you marshal the work to a background thread doesn't mean that making the request synchronously is a good idea. You should use `NSURLSession`'s asynchronous API, and then cancel the request in the event that your app goes to the background (or is asked to terminate.) Using asynchronous API is more work, but is the more correct approach. `dispatch_async` is not necessarily a sufficient "adapter."

Comment: Are you suggesting I should discard dispatch_async and work solely with NSURL asynchronous? Or should I use dispatch_async AND NSURL asynchronous?

Comment: If you use the `NSURLSession` async API you shouldn't need to use `dispatch_async` any more.

Answer (score 1):

These are watchdog timeout crash reports, which you can recognize by the infamous "ate bad food" (0x8badf00d) exception code. More info on how to decipher the crash log and potential solutions can be found at :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1693/_index.html